# Save Remote Desktop Connection Settings to RDP File using Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, remote-access, remote-desktop, rdp

Im trying to doing portable client generator as windows remote desktop connection.
[RDP Client Generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMGkb.png)

When the create button is clicked, from the client whose information is entered,
How can a connect type icon be created on the desktop that will enable the client to log in?
[John.connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ahkn.png)

I would be very grateful if you could write a code sample. thanks for the answers in advance

Comment: Looks like that application registers itself as the default handler for `.connect` files, and writes them in their own format.

Comment: @CodeCaster maybe someone tried to output .connect file :)